# springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin configuration isn't applied

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

I'm currently testing springdoc to integrate it in other projects. I found out, that the maven plugin doesn't apply any configuration settings, e.g. the *outputfilename* can't be set. If I'm calling *mvn verify*, the plugin just generates `target/openapi.json`!
What I'm doing wrong?

The project has just a sample controller with some openapi anntotations.

The pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>codes.thischwa</groupId>
    <artifactId>pg</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootPlayground</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.49</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
                    <outputfilename>api.json</outputfilename>
                    <outputdir>${basedir}</outputdir>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is this a bug? Or is it a problem between my ear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some typos/case-errors

It’s outputFileName and outputDir.

Comment: I copy-and-paste it from a blog, goof. Thanks a lot!